# Seeking to a line in a file in g++

Tags: c++, file-io, g++

Is there a way that I can seek to a certain line in a file to read or write data?

Let's say I want to write some data starting on the 10th line in a text file.  There might be some data already in the first few lines, or the file could even be empty.  Is there a way I can seek directly to the line I want without having to worry about what's already in the file?

Comment: g++ is a *compiler*, C++ is a *language*.

Comment: g++ (or gcc) is a compiler collection.

Comment: @helper: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html#G_002b_002b-and-GCC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can seek to a position in a file, but that position must be a character offset from the start, end or current position - see for example [fseek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/). There is no way of seeking to  a particular line, unless all the lines are exactly the same length.

Answer (score 6):

Only if the lines are all the same length (seek to `9 * bytes_per_line`). Otherwise, you'll just have to scan your way to the appropriate spot in the file.

Also be wary of writing into the middle of a file. It may not do what you expect (insert new lines). It will simply overwrite whatever content is already there, and won't respect existing line boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to process the data to find the line delimiters (unless you have fixed length lines). Have a look at getline(), ftell() and fseek(). http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/readline/cpp.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The easy best way is to read the file in memory inserting for instance each line in a vector of strings, then modifying/adding whatever you want, and re-write each line in a new file.

(supposing the file fits in memory)